# Stop flash animation after 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, flash, animation

i'm running a flash countdown is a countdown that counts down to a specified date. i'd like the countdown to stop after playing for 30 seconds. What do i need to do?

```
counter.onEnterFrame = function(){
currentDate = new Date();
currentMillisecs = currentDate.getTime();
this.msecs = eventMillisecs - currentMillisecs;
if (this.msecs <= 0){
    // the event time has been reached!
    // play the next frame for the result of the countdown.     
    play();
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `setInterval`, or `setTimeout`, or track the time elapsed with `getTimer()`.

Here is an example of the latter:

```
var initalTime = getTimer();
counter.onEnterFrame = function(){
    if(getTimer() - initialTime > 30000) //stop counting

    ....
```

Or setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(30000, cancelCountdown);

function cnacelCountdown(){
     //stop your countdown
}
```